# Telegram bot API on message not triggering on group leave

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have the following code for a telegram bot in typescript:

```
import TelegramBot, { Message } from 'node-telegram-bot-api'

const bot = new TelegramBot(MY_TOKEN, { polling: {
  params: {
    allowed_updates: ['chat_member', 'message', 'my_chat_member']
  }
}})

bot.on('message', async (msg) => {
  console.log("MESSAGE")
})
```

The bot.on('message') is triggering correctly when a user joins a group which has as an admin the bot, but it doesn't trigger when the user leaves the group.

Is this the correct approach to get notified on users' group leave? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not the right way to do it.

Actually, the `message` event is for the incoming message updates such as your bot receives a text, or a photo, video, location, things like that.

If you want to properly listen for the updates about user joined/left you should listen to the `chat_member` updates. Here's a simple snippet that might help:

```js
bot.on('chat_member', (chat_member) => {
    if (chat_member.new_chat_member.status == 'member') {
        // User joined the chat
    }

    if (chat_member.new_chat_member.status == 'left') {
        // User left the chat
    }
})
```

See the [ChatMemberUpdated](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmemberupdated) documentation for more detailed info on available properties.

Comment: The event is not getting triggered when listening to chat_member updates.